# ArcMap crashes when trying to merge training samples during supervised classification?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, image-mosaic

I have a recurrent problem. When I select training samples from a subset of a landsat mosaic, arcmap crashes ALWAYS! Specifically it crashes when i try to merge training samples, sometimes when i try to visualize the scatter plot. My training samples dont have so many pixels.

Some background:

1. I did a landsat multi-band mosaic of the whole coast of Peru (14 landsat scenes).
2. I then kept only the coast by clipping with a mask that covered the first 5 km of the coast.
3. I divided the coast strip in three parts (North, center, south) and finally in each part I identified and clipped all the wetlands (they are not so many). This last multiband tiff containing patches of wetlands is what i have been using to perform the supervised classification.

I tried ArcGIS Desktop 10.3 in two computers and the same happened, I reinstalled the Arcmap, i optimized my computer and I also re-did the mosaic. I am not doing very complicated procedures and arcmap always crashes.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  What happens when you start by doing a landsat multi-band mosaic of only part of the coast of Peru (2 landsat scenes)?  What do you mean when you say "crashes"?  Are you seeing a Serious Application Error or something else?

Comment: Have you tried disabling the background geoprocessing for this task.  I find that when I have this issue (ArcMap crashing every time I try to run a certain process), if I turn off background geoprocessing, it stops crashing (most times).

Comment: Thanks! Jbalk: I did disable the background proccesing and the same happenend unfortunately.   PolyGeo: When I did the the multi-band mosaic of only one part of the coast of Peru everything work fine but as i was digitizing and merging training samples the program would shut-down (crash) and a Serious Application Error would come out.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make arcmap stop shutting down when merging training samples. The apparent problem was that i was using a multi-band mosaic ofLandsat 8 (Bands 1-8). The solution was to use the "Extract Band function" in the image analysis window and remove bands 1 and 8. Then I saved the output as a .tiff (16 bit unsigned). After doing that the image clasification modules works perfectly and it doesn't crash anymore.